# How can I get the Amazon Cognito Identity SDK working in Aurelia?

Tags: amazon-cognito, aurelia

I am trying to get the Amazon Cognito Identity SDK working in Aurelia. I do not have a lot of Javascript experience and am very unfamiliar with the various dependency systems.

I installed the Cognito SDK using: `npm install --save amazon-cognito-identity-js`

I then edited my `aurelia_project/aurelia.json` file as suggested in the Aurelia documentation to include a new client library dependency in build.bundles vendor-bundle dependencies:

```
"sjcl",
"jsbn",
{
  "name": "aws-sdk",
  "path": "../node_modules/aws-sdk/",
  "main": "dist/aws-sdk"
},
{
  "name": "amazon-cognito-identity-js",
  "path": "../node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist",
  "main": "amazon-cognito-identity.min"
}
```

However, when I try to run the code using `au run` I get the error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/nathanskone/Projects/scc/aurelia-app/src/xmlbuilder.js'`

I have tried to include xmlbuilder in my aurelia.json to no avail. When it is included I end up getting this error about lodash: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/nathanskone/Projects/scc/aurelia-app/src/lodash/object/assign.js'`

I haven't found any way to get past the lodash error.

Is there anyone out there familiar with the Aurelia dependency system that could help?

Thanks,
Nathan

**EDIT #2:** While I got past the xmlbuilder/lodash errors, I have run into further errors trying to bundle the aws-sdk. Here is my current aurelia.json:

```
"dependencies": [
  {
    "name": "xmlbuilder",
    "path": "../node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib",
    "main": "index"
  },
  {
    "name": "aws-sdk",
    "path": "../node_modules/aws-sdk",
    "main": "index",
    "resources": ["lib/region_config.json"]
  },
```

And the error I am currently getting:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/nathanskone/Projects/scc/aurelia-app/src/crypto.js'`

If I remove the resources (lib/region_config.json) then I get this error instead:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/nathanskone/Projects/scc/aurelia-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/region_config.json.js'`

I think crypto is actually an object defined in aws-sdk/lib/util.js, which is required by aws-sdk/lib/region_config.js.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the compiled library instead, using the compiled lib bundled just fine.
Also the library seems to define `window.AWS`, so injecting it or not will work

```js
{
    "name": "aws-sdk",
    "path": "../node_modules/aws-sdk/dist",
    "main": "aws-sdk.min",
    "exports": "AWS"
}
```

UPDATE:

It seems the only way to import those libraries is by using the prepend section, the libraries write to the window variable so it can still be accesible to your app scripts, only by not importing them like ES6 modules.

```js
    "prepend": [
      "node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.min.js",
      "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js",
      "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js",
      "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
      "scripts/require.js"
    ],
```

Comment: That does work for the AWS-SDK alone, but as soon as I add the amazon-cognito-identity-js it complains about `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/nathanskone/Projects/scc/aurelia-app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/region_config.json.js'` again.

Comment: That did it! Although I also had to add jsbn and sjcl to the prepend section since they are both required by the Amazon Cognito SDK.