# How to bundle AWS Cognito within Aurelia Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, bundle, aurelia

Since my previous post [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714424/how-can-i-get-the-amazon-cognito-identity-sdk-working-in-aurelia?answertab=oldest#tab-top) was deleted, even though it was pretty explicit in presenting the problem (in that context), I will try again as a stand alone question.

I am trying to bundle Amazon Cognito with `aurelia.json`. I have followed everything I could thin of in the answers provided by jsachs and Nathan in the [mentioned article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714424/how-can-i-get-the-amazon-cognito-identity-sdk-working-in-aurelia?answertab=oldest#tab-top), however I think something is incomplete.

```
  {
    "name": "account-components-bundle.js",
    "source": {
      "include": [
        "**/components/account/**/*.js",
        "**/components/account/**/*.{html,css}"
      ]
    },
    "dependencies": [
      {
          "name": "aws-sdk",
          "path": "../node_modules/aws-sdk/dist",
          "main": "aws-sdk.min",
          "exports": "AWS"
      } 
    ],
    "prepend": [
      "node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.min.js",
      "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js",
      "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js",
      "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
      "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
    ]
  },
```

If you add only the prepend directive, `au build` will not throw any error, however I have no way of calling the Cognito classes.

Adding the dependencies directive in the form above will eventually bundle the package, however at page load you will get the following error (please keep in mind I am not calling anything yet within our own code):

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Script error for "aws-sdk/global", needed by: components/account/login
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:4419:17)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5989:36)
From previous event:
    at DefaultLoader.loadModule (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:14914:14)
    at ViewEngine.importViewModelResource (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:23006:26)
    at CompositionEngine.ensureViewModel (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24276:32)
    at CompositionEngine.createController (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24252:19)
    at CompositionEngine._createControllerAndSwap (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24227:19)
    at CompositionEngine.compose (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24313:21)
    at processInstruction (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24798:32)
    at Compose.bind (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24689:7)
    at Controller.bind (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:23196:24)
    at View.bind (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:21200:24)
    at If._runValueChanged (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24887:19)
    at If.valueChanged (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24842:31)
    at If.bind (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24831:12)
From previous event:
    at CompositionEngine._createControllerAndSwap (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24227:45)
    at CompositionEngine.compose (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24313:21)
    at TemplatingEngine.compose (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:24576:38)
    at Aurelia.setRoot (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:13886:21)
    at Object._callee$ (https://white.dev/dist/app-bundle.js:86:37)
    at tryCatch (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:3:27199)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:3:28901)
    at Generator.t.(anonymous function) [as next] (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:3:27447)
    at step (https://white.dev/dist/app-bundle.js:25:44)
    at https://white.dev/dist/app-bundle.js:36:29
From previous event:
    at step (https://white.dev/dist/app-bundle.js:35:55)
    at https://white.dev/dist/app-bundle.js:43:24
From previous event:
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://white.dev/dist/app-bundle.js:22:20)
    at Object.configure (https://white.dev/dist/app-bundle.js:97:25)
    at https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:12465:29
From previous event:
    at config (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:12460:56)
    at https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:12496:14
From previous event:
    at bootstrap (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:12495:26)
    at https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:12482:9
    at <anonymous>
From previous event:
    at run (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:12477:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:12502:37)
    at Object.execCb (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5947:33)
    at Module.check (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5134:51)
    at Module.enable (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5427:22)
    at Object.enable (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5808:39)
    at Module.<anonymous> (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5412:33)
    at https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:4385:23
    at each (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:4310:31)
    at Module.enable (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5364:17)
    at Module.init (https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5039:26)
    at https://white.dev/dist/aurelia-bundle.js:5711:36
```

The moment I go further and try to extend the dependencies (not use the already compiled libraries), I get to the same old problem mentioned in the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39714424/how-can-i-get-the-amazon-cognito-identity-sdk-working-in-aurelia?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

```
    "dependencies": [
      {
        "name": "lodash",
        "path": "../node_modules/lodash",
        "main": "index"
      },
      {
        "name": "xmlbuilder",
        "path": "../node_modules/xmlbuilder",
        "main": "lib/index"
      },
      {
          "name": "aws-sdk",
          "path": "../node_modules/aws-sdk",
          "main": "lib/aws",
          "exports": "AWS"
      }
    ],
```

This dependencies, when running `au build`, will lead to

```
File not found or not accessible: /path/to/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/region_config_data.json.js. Requested by /path/to/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/aws.js
{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/path/to/project/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/region_config_data.json.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:491:33)
    at Object.exports.readFileSync (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/file-system.js:74:13)
    at fileRead (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/bundled-source.js:101:27)
    at Object.context.fileRead (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:179:18)
    at Object.context.load (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:370:32)
    at Module.load (eval at <anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:832:29)
    at Module.fetch (eval at <anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:822:66)
    at Module.check (eval at <anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:854:30)
    at Module.enable (eval at <anonymous> (/path/to/project/node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/build/amodro-trace/lib/loader/Loader.js:14:1), <anonymous>:1173:22)
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
```

I think this is caused by the fact that `requirejs` in comparison to `nodejs require()` may not support loading json files and it always expects the file to be a `js` one.

At this point in my debugging quest I am kinda stuck. Has anyone got any suggestions in how this can be achieved? I would be very grateful.

To avoid and exclude some previous questions to my approaches, I have tried to add to the bundle dependencies "amazon-cognito-identity-js" as well, in more than one form (both `dist` and `lib` files). The outcome is the same as the one above. I get stuck at `json.js` error.

**Edit 1**

I managed to clean all compile errors with the following form for `aurelia.json`, however the classes are not loading properly.

```
"bundles": [
  {
    "name": "app-bundle.js",
    "source": {
      "include": [
        "**/src/main.js",
        "**/src/app.js",
        "**/src/environment.js",
        "**/src/app.{html,css}"
      ]
    }
  },
  ...
  {
    "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
    "dependencies": [
      ...
      {
        "name": "lodash",
        "path": "../node_modules/lodash",
        "main": "index"
      },
      {
        "name": "xmlbuilder",
        "path": "../node_modules/xmlbuilder",
        "main": "lib/index"
      },
      {
        "name": "aws-sdk",
        "path": "../node_modules/aws-sdk",
        "main": "dist/aws-sdk",
        "exports": "AWS"
      }
    ],
    "append": [
      "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js",
      "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js"
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the json file to the list of files that need to be included for that dep?

Comment: @AshleyGrant Have tried the following ` { "name": "aws-sdk",  "path": "../node_modules/aws-sdk", "main": "lib/aws", "exports": "AWS",  "resources": [ "lib/region_config_data.json" ]  }`. The result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Funny to give the answer myself, but hey... if it will help others...

I managed to bundle the scripts by prepending them in the aurelia-bundle.js ahead of every other scripts that need to be loaded. Please understand, that (for me), placing the scripts in any other position that the following, will end up in neither loading correctly or not loading at all.

Don't pretend this is a general solution, but hey... works for me.
Please find a more detailed history [here](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/issues/418).

```
{
  "name": "aurelia-bundle.js",
  "prepend": [
    "node_modules/aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.min.js",
    "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/aws-cognito-sdk.min.js",
    "node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/dist/amazon-cognito-identity.min.js",
    "node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js",
    "node_modules/whatwg-fetch/fetch.js",
    "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",
    "node_modules/aurelia-cli/lib/resources/scripts/configure-bluebird.js",
    "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
  ],
  "dependencies": [
    "aurelia-animator-css",
    "aurelia-binding",
    "aurelia-bootstrapper",
    "aurelia-dependency-injection",
    "aurelia-event-aggregator",
```